# Different Servers for SSIS and Database

Tags: ssis

We are going to use different SQL servers for SSIS and database. Currently both are in same servers. We have a package which calls another package inside that. But I am not able to select the secondary package location from SQL server option in the editor as the MSDB is in SSIS server not in database server. Should the MSDB in database server for me to select it or can we use SSIS server to deploy MSDB?

Thanks
Ajeesh

Comment: So are you talking about selecting the package using the Execute Package Task editor?

Answer (score 0):

1. So first, create a connection to your SSIS Server in your package. Let's name it **SSISServer**.
2. Create your Execute Package task.
3. In the editor, under the Package Tab, under ReferenceType, choose External Reference.
4. Under Location, choose SQL Server.
5. Under Connection, choose SSISServer.
6. Under PackageName, browse to your package.

This is how you execute packages on different servers from the package that is running.